# Flutter http.get not executing

Tags: http, flutter, dart

I am very new to `Flutter`, and stuck at the following problem:

```dart
  child: RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
   fetchData();
  },
  // ...
  fetchData() async {
    final res = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      print("it works");
      return json.decode(res.body);
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
  // ...
```

when i remove the http.get part it prints "it works" so i think the problem is in the http.get executing.

Comment: needs more explanation, does it throw error `Failed to load post`??

Comment: no it doesn't nothing happens

Comment: Try curl or postman for the same url, post the result

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0HAZMeh

Comment: Post header details of postman aswell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running Flutter clean still don't know how

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I found there was a very sneaky error on my part. I essentially had a class with a method that looked like:

`void execute() async {...}`

Inside of `execute()`, I was **properly** using:

`final response = await http.get(...);`

The log message immediately before the HTTP request would fire, but the one immediately after was nowhere to be seen. This was all inside of a try-catch, so I wasn't missing an exception. The issue was **outside** of the class itself. My call to the `execute` method looked like:

```
try {
  thing.execute();
} catch (e) {...}

return true;
```

The issue is that final `return` statement is occurring before that `execute` method finishes the HTTP call. The solution is simply to modify `execute` to return a Future (say, `return Future.value(true)`), and then call `execute` using `await` like so:

`final status = await thing.execute();`

or

`await thing.execute();`

The advantage to the former is that you can also check the status of the operation afterwards. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I always use Postman to gen code dart, in your case i rebuild the `fetchData()` like this:

```
  fetchData() async {
    var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //This line will be print to console the result of request you called,if you want to use it like a object please creat a model
      debugPrint(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

Model of this Request:

```
    class ModelName {
  int? userId;
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? body;

  ModelName({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  ModelName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['userId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['userId'] = userId;
    data['id'] = id;
    data['title'] = title;
    data['body'] = body;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the **onPressed** **async** and add an **await** to **fetchData**().

Answer (score 0):

Make your method of type `Future`, and let it return the data type `dynamic` like this. And then call it wherever you want.

```
  Future<dynamic> fetchData() async {
    final res = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      print("it works");
      return json.decode(res.body);
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

And call it via this, since you are returning the data

```
     child: RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // the value is the call back function data which you're returning 
        fetchData().then((value){
             // since the data it return is a dynamic one
             print(value.toString());
        });
      }
     )
```

If you don't want to return any data, and just simply call the method. Then do this

```
  fetchData() async {
    final res = await http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      print("it works");
      // do not return
      print(json.decode(res.body).toString());
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

And simply call like your method call in your code

```
    child: RaisedButton(
      // no need of anything now
      onPressed: () => fetchData()
     )
```